# Property '.readonly' not found

Tags: kubernetes, qemu, readonly, kata-containers

While following the kata on k8s instructions

https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers/blob/main/docs/how-to/run-kata-with-k8s.md

I just got stuck in ContainerCreating Status
By seeing logs by

journalctl -fu crio

**time="2024-03-17T22:53:19.690006247+09:00" level=error msg="qemu-system-x86_64: -object memory-backend-file,id=mem0,mem-path=/usr/share/kata-containers/kata-ubuntu-latest.image,size=268435456,readonly=on: Property '.readonly' not found" name=containerd-shim-v2 pid=569880 qemuPid=569898 sandbox=4dbfa140157b8ef4bbb4a9bde72ff609990f8146a406c49a994cc47aa8e35bd1 source=virtcontainers/hypervisor subsystem=qemu**

I get stuck in this problem

My kubernetes is 1.23, kata-container is 3.2.0

how do i fix this?

I tried to change the read only option but i dont know how.
There arent any related options in configuration.toml
Need help